# how can i check using jQuery if something is hidden?

Tags: jquery

I want to check if a element is hidden based on that i want to add a condition. I just want to use jQuery please help me with that.

I have actually a selectbox which is having id param. When it is hidden I do not want to perform any action but when it is visible and having value as country I want to show next select box containing countries.

```
param = $('#param').val();
if(param =='country') {//show next box}
```

I am not sure how to incorporate that show next box only when it is visible

Comment: i have this condition param = jQuery("#param").val(); 
        
     if(param =='country' && $("#param").is(":visible"))
     { which is not working thats why i asked the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case it's totally different matter. What you need is such code:

```
param = jQuery("#param").val();
if(param =='country' && $("#" + param).is(":visible")) {
    //do something....
}
```

You need to pass `param` as variable to the jQuery selector, then it will look for element with ID of `country` (the value of the variable) and check if it's visible.

Edit: regarding your new edit, try such code:

```
var oParam = $('#param');
if (oParam.is(":visible")) {
    paramValue = oParam.val();
    if(paramValue == 'country') {
        //show next box
    }
}
```

This will check the value and show next box only when `param` is visible.

Comment: please re read the question its different. I want to pick the value of a visible box.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($(selector).is(":hidden")){
    // hidden
}
else {
    // visible
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
is_hidden = ($('...').css('display') == 'none' || $('...').css('visibility') == 'hidden');
if (is_hidden) {
    // what you want
}
```

Comment: See Igor answer, jQuery has shortcut for this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do this with $(..elementSelector..).is(':hidden') returns boolean.